# Can I say that "unremarkable transverse peculiar velocity" is "vernacularly dissonant"? Is there a better description?

Tags: phrase-requests, prepositional-phrases

In the Astronomy SE question [What does “unremarkable transverse peculiar velocity” mean exactly, and how is it calculated here?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39003/7982) I made the following comment:

> The peculiar phrase "unremarkable transverse peculiar velocity" is vernacularly dissonant, but parenthetical clarifications in the body of the paper help with that

I feel that in common spoken English when we say something is peculiar it is unusual, and we are *making a remark* specifically to indicate said peculiarity. So calling something both *unremarkable* and *peculiar* within the space of a few words is dissonant.

Of course taken in context, the term *peculiar velocity* [is well defined in galactic astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peculiar_velocity#Galactic_astronomy):

> In galactic astronomy, peculiar motion refers to the motion of an object (usually a star) relative to a Galactic rest frame.

and in this context it just means that this parameter is unremarkable, it's not too high or too low for its location.

**Question:** But was my remark that it is "vernacularly dissonant" correct for what I'd wanted to say, or should I have said "vernacularly contradictory" or something else instead?

Comment: help with correct tagging welcomed

Comment: The first line of the answer seems to imply that there isn't a dissonance because *"Peculiar velocity" is a fixed term*, however I think you said exactly what you meant; you were just wrong... ?

Comment: @Mazura it's always a possibility; wrong about what exactly, "vernacularly dissonant"? No I don't think so, "transverse peculiar velocity" is not a common phrase, so in the way that ordinary people speak it is not wrong to say it is dissonant. It's simply uninformed, and ordinary people fight tirelessly to maintain the right to remain uninformed!

Comment: How about "gobbledygook"?

Comment: @HotLicks I'll go for "apparent gobbledygook" :-)